# Spring boot admin oauth2 keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, spring-boot-admin

I have a spring boot application secured with keycloak. I have a client in keycloak specific for this application.

Now I want to deploy spring boot admin and also implement keycloak on it. My question is how can I let the spring-boot-admin talk to my app?

Comment: User authenticates while accessing spring-boot-admin and sends bearer-
 token to your app, You need to setup bearer-only client for your app.

Comment: My spring boot admin has security via keycloak (access-type = confidential)
My app also has this type of security to be able to login.
Can I add a second 'client' with bearer only and configure my app to use this? Do you have an example of this?